# Matplotlib: Insert label at bottom of y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am plotting two timeseries with matplotlib. The first example plot has a y-axis with lower limit of 1 * 10^6, and upper limit of 1 * 10^10. See below:

[image: Two timeseries: y-axis limits 1 * 10 ** 6, 1 * 10 ** 10]

The second example has y-axis with lower limit of 1 * 10^8, and upper limit of 1 * 10^10. See below:

[image: Two timeseries: y-axis limits 1 * 10 ** 8, 1 * 10 ** 10]

I would like to keep the y-axis linear. I would like to know, is there a way in matplotlib to insert a label at the bottom of the y-axis to record the lower limit? Otherwise it is difficult to distinguish these two plots.

Many thanks!

Comment: Set the yticks manually, assuming I understand the question. Or are you looking for an annotation?

Comment: No, I suppose set the y-ticks manually. I just wondered if there was an argument available in Axes.tick_params (that I was unaware of) that would automatically include a ytick at the base of the axis.